# C# Windows Form - Duvidas sobre Session

Tags: c#, winforms, session

Estou precisando, guardar uma informação pelo tempo que o usuário estiver logado em meu software, pesquisei e vi que para paginas da web feitas com ASP.NET existe o objeto `SESSION`, mas e para Windows Form?

as informações que preciso e nome do usuário, tenho a ID dela inserida na tela de login. mas preciso apresentar o nome do usuário em um form.

Answer (score 3):

Achei a solução, segue abaixo:

Fonte: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3215/trabalhando-com-sessao-dentro-do-windows-forms.aspx

Na plataforma Windows Forms o pessoal acha difícil manter esse tipo de sessão com variáveis e informações, porém, existe uma maneira simples de gravar sessão usando a plataforma desktop sem qualquer problema.

Trabalhar com Session é simples e tranqüilo. Logo depois de entrar com o usuário e senha, as variáveis precisam ser preenchidas e guardadas na sessão para uso ou verificação futura.

Usando Windows Forms, o primeiro passo é criar uma classe do tipo pública e estática.

**Criando Classe**

Clique com o botão direito em cima do seu projeto ou dentro de uma pasta UTIL, escolha a opção Add / New Item...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de dar o nome (SessaoSistema.cs) e clicar no botão Add, coloque os seguintes dados:

Passo 1: Coloque a palavra Public Static no início da classe.

```
public static class SessaoSistema

{}
```

Passo 2: Gere variáveis Get e Set dentro da classe. Elas devem ficar estáticas dentro da classe SessaoSistema.

```
//usuario
private static Int32 _usuarioId;
private static String _nomeUsuario;
private static String _emailUsuario;

//get e set
public static String UsuarioId
{
   get { return SessaoSistema._usuarioId; }
   set { SessaoSistema._usuarioId = value; }
}
public static String NomeUsuario
{
   get { return SessaoSistema._nomeUsuario; }
   set { SessaoSistema._nomeUsuario = value; }
}
public static String EmailUsuario
{
   get { return SessaoSistema._emailUsuario; }
   set { SessaoSistema._emailUsuario = value; }
}
```

**Usando Classe de Sessão**

Agora na tela de login, depois que entrar com usuário e senha do sistema desktop basta preencher as informações da seguinte maneira.

```
//depois do login ok
SessaoSistema.NomeUsuario = txtNomeUsuario.text;
SessaoSistema.UsuarioId = usuarioId;
SessaoSistema.EmailUsuario = txtEmail.text;
```

Em qualquer lugar do sistema você pode pegar os dados armazenados no depois do Login do usuário apenas digitando e variável SessaoSistema.Propriedade (por exemplo: SessaoSistema.NomeUsuario.

Fonte: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3215/trabalhando-com-sessao-dentro-do-windows-forms.aspx

Mais informações:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599127/session-for-windows-forms-application-in-c-sharp

Comment: Poderia colocar a resposta aqui e manter os links apenas como referência?

Comment: Claro. vou alterar.